# Array Out of Bounds in K-Fold algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, spring, intellij-idea, k-fold

i had a problem when running my project, and the error is array out of bounds can you help me?
this is my methods

```
public double hitungAkurasi(TrainRecord[] trainRecords, TestRecord[] testRecords, int K) {
    if (K <= 0) {
        System.out.println("K should be larger than 0!");
        return -1;
    }

    //normalisasi
    TrainRecord[] trainingSet = trainRecords;
    TestRecord[] testingSet = testRecords;

    //System.out.println("Test" + testRecords);

    trainingSet = (TrainRecord[]) normalisasi(trainingSet);
    testingSet = (TestRecord[]) normalisasi(testingSet);

    Record[] join = trainingSet;


    //test those TestRecords one by one
    int numOfTestingRecord = testingSet.length;
    int numOfTrainingRecord = trainingSet.length;
    int sumNumOfRecord = numOfTestingRecord + numOfTrainingRecord;

    //train record
    for (int i = 0; i < (sumNumOfRecord) / K; i++){
        TrainRecord[] neighbors = findKNearestNeighbors(trainingSet, testingSet[i], K);
        int classLabel = classify(neighbors);
        testingSet[i].predictedLabel = classLabel; //assign the predicted label to TestRecord
    }
    for (int j = ((numOfTrainingRecord + 1) * sumNumOfRecord) / K; j < sumNumOfRecord; j++){
        TrainRecord[] neighbors = findKNearestNeighbors(trainingSet, testingSet[j], K);
        int classLabel = classify(neighbors);
        testingSet[j].predictedLabel = classLabel; //assign the predicted label to TestRecord
    }

    //test record
    for (int t = (numOfTestingRecord * sumNumOfRecord) / K; t < ((numOfTestingRecord + 1) * sumNumOfRecord) / K; t++){
        TrainRecord[] neighbors = findKNearestNeighbors(trainingSet, testingSet[t], K);
        int classLabel = classify(neighbors);
        testingSet[t].predictedLabel = classLabel; //assign the predicted label to TestRecord
    }

    int correctPrediction = 0;
    for (int l = 0; l < numOfTestingRecord; l++) {

        if (testingSet[l].predictedLabel == testingSet[l].classLabel) {
            correctPrediction++;
        }
    }

    return ((double) correctPrediction / numOfTestingRecord) * 100;
}
```

when i try to disable the test record looping the program successfully success, but when i enable that looping, i had a error Array out of bounds in here

```
TrainRecord[] neighbors = findKNearestNeighbors(trainingSet, testingSet[t], K);
```

can you help me fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If it's throwing an "Array index out of bounds" in your "test record" loop, that means that your index *t* at some point takes a value greater than the size of the array that you are accessing in that loop. You can check this modifying the loop to print those values and/or check if t goes out of range:

```
for (int t = (numOfTestingRecord * sumNumOfRecord) / K; t < ((numOfTestingRecord + 1) * sumNumOfRecord) / K; t++){
        System.out.println("Array size: "+testingSet.length);
        System.out.println("Current index: "+t);   
        if (t > testingSet.length) {
            System.out.println("If you see this message you are in trouble");    
        }    
        TrainRecord[] neighbors = findKNearestNeighbors(trainingSet, testingSet[t], K);
        int classLabel = classify(neighbors);
        testingSet[t].predictedLabel = classLabel; //assign the predicted label to TestRecord
    }
```

You'll probably need to change the initialization of *t* or the condition to end the loop.

Comment: i see the message sir, then what should i do to fix that?

Comment: Well, you should have seen at what point *t* is bigger than the size of your array. As I said, either the initialization of *t* or the condition to terminate the loop allow *t* to have a value that exceeds the size of the array and you should change them to ensure it doesn't happen. How many times did the loop run before you saw the message? What is the size of the array and the value of t when you see the message?

Comment: the array size is 122
and the index is 14859 sir. 
how can the index exceeds the array, even though my manual calculations do not exceed the array,

Comment: That means that at one point (numOfTestingRecord*sumNumOfRecord)/K is 14859. numOfTestingRecord already holds the size of the array you are indexing with t, if I followed your code correctly. And then you are further multiplying it by sumNumOfRecord which is the sum of the lengths of both of your arrays. Even if you divide it by K it's clearly giving you problems, so you should verify your calculations again. Because the root cause of your issue is the value of t exceeding the size of the array, so you have to make sure when t takes a value it can't be greater than the size of the array.

Comment: oh i got it sir, okay i will try it again,